# simple currency converter with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i have two questions.(sorry if my questions seem simple to you but i'm new to kotlin)

The first I try to do a simple calculation with a value entered in one field which is multiplied by a defined value, to get the result in another field.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    Convertisseur.setOnClickListener {

        val idr = editTextNumber.text.toString().toDouble()
        val dollardft = 0.00007

        resultDollar.text = (idr * dollardft).toString()
    }
```

following this code I have an error on the result = Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Editable! was expected.

My second question, is it possible to do without a calculate button to obtain the result instantly.
thank you very much for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Use `setText` instead

```kotlin
resultDollar.setText((idr * dollardft).toString())
```

or

```kotlin
fun String.toEditable(): Editable =  Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(this)
resultDollar.text = (idr * dollardft).toString().toEditable()
```

Comment: Great thanks, it works. is it possible to do the same thing without using the button, that the result field is filled automatically as the amount is entered?

Comment: @Marc75 you can add a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/TextWatcher) to the EditText

Comment: thank you very much, i will try to set it up because i don't know